# CSRF в django

Tags: python, django

Получаю 403-ю, версия питона 2.6, джанго 1.4
вот так передаю в шаблон данные

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.core.context_processors import csrf
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))    
    if 'q' in request.POST:
    q = request.POST['q']
    return render_to_response('index.html', c)
    else:
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'q': 'error', 'c': c} )
```

в шаблоне:
    {{ q }}

```
<form action="" method="POST" />
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

settings.py

```
....
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

....
```

Все что нужно сделано, а получаю все равно **CSRF verification failed. Request aborted**.

Answer (score 3):

Вы должны всегда использовать RequestContext, для вашего случая

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```